# how to return stores with only receiver tag against stores with donor tag

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: as]

What formulae should I put in column E, such that it takes value from column B with only the store which belong to receiver category.

For eg. Store 12 should receive stock from store 5, store 13 should receive stock from store 19 and so on

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use following formula-

```
=IF(D3="Donor",INDEX(FILTER($B$3:$B$13,$D$3:$D$13="Receiver"),ROWS($B$3:$B3)),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks sir, it worked. Issue is I have many SKUs in the main file, so how to use this for multiple SKUs and stock locations?

Comment: @PankajAndani Then can you share more sample so that we can suggest more elegant formula?

Comment: Can I mail that to you on your Gmail ID please?

Comment: @PankajAndani I am reachable at `harun24hr@gmail.com`.